# Yarn job crashes with exit code 143 even though node has available memory

Tags: hadoop, memory-management, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

My Map task is timing out with exit code 143, which I believe is a memory problem. From what I understand, from my settings, each container will receive 3gb of memory, 2.5gb of that will be allocated to java heap. When I check the memory availability on the yarn web UI, I see that **Mem Used** does not ever go pass **Mem Avail** but yet my job times out after 600 seconds.

Could this be happening because my job uses too much java heap and crashes?

```
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>3072</value>

    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx2560M</value>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. your mapper is performing some task  which is taking  more than 600 seconds, the nodemanager thinks its dead and hence killing it.
2. Please ack in between the performing the task, that the task is alive.
3. In case you are updating the counters the ack will be done automatically.
4. Increase the timeout more than 600 seconds